# how can I set ImageView position in dpi fro android api 8?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, dpi

my android app supports Android api 8

and I want to move an object `x dpi` to the left.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform the amount of `dip` to the right amount of `pixels` for the given screen.

This is the formula you should use:

```
pixels = dip * (density / 160)
```

the `(density / 160)` part is known as the `density scale factor`. You can get this scale factor using the following code.

```
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Than calculate the right amount of pixels from the given amount of dip and round it:

```
int pixels (int) (dip * scale + 0.5f);
```

In function form it would look like this.

```
public int getPixelFromDip(float dip){
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dip * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Rolf